# Detect bottom of bounding box - Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, bounding-box

How would I detect the bottom of the bounding box method in a sprite?

I use `CGRectIntersectsRect` to detect a touch however I want to only detect the touch on the bottom of the `_ball.boundingbox`

```
 if(CGRectIntersectsRect(_ball.boundingBox, sprite.boundingBox)){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a rectangle of a very small height to emulate the bottom line of the bounding box and detect collisions off it using the code you have give above , something along these lines.

```
CGRect bottomLineRect = CGRectMake(_ball.position.x,_ball.position.y,_ball.boundingBox.size.width, 1);
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(bottomLineRect, sprite.boundingBox)){
    // collision code here
}
```